# Order of displaying information

Tags: layout, content, profile, order

Is there a golden rule to go by when deciding the order in which users are going to see the content?

I made a mockup in which I compare two cases. The first one is the one I'd like to apply. The second one is the generic Facebook/Instagram post.

[image]

The way I see, on FB/ig (case 2) the first thing a user will see when scrolling is the author of the post, followed by the actual post (whether it is a video/picture/text) then followed by icons (like, share etc.) and on the last row the description of the post.
A tl;dr would be, see the author, see the content, decide what to do with that (comment, like, share) and at the end read something about it. Seems like a natural flow.

In my case (case 1), the aforementioned 'natural flow' is disrupted as I serve the content (whether it is going to be a picture, video or wall of text) first, followed by profile/user and icons (on the same row). On the last row I'd like to place the description.

I don't have arguments to back my changes more than I am not into the way Facebook and Instagram looks like. I cannot ignore the fact that they (most likely) invested a ton into research on how to serve content.

In the end, this kind of dilemma is going to be solved with AB testing but I wanted some other opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The 'golden rule' is that you order the content the way you want your users to see it.**

Positioning is one thing. Users often read in an [F-shaped pattern: two horizontal stripes followed by a vertical stripe.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/)

However, there's more than just positioning. There's also size, color, contrast and alignment to name a few. [Read more about that here.](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/visual-hierarchy-organizing-content-to-follow-natural-eye-movement-patterns)

**Putting theory to practice**

Think of your users and their goals. What do you want them to see first? What do you want them to do with what they see? Think of that deeply. Create user journeys, user tasks and user scenarios. Finally, create your flow (including all the above) accordingly. Good lcuk!